# Access to azure app setting environment variables from nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I set environment variables in the azure app service through the settings
[image]

and I want to change to the environment variable I created through the code How can it be accessed?
something like this

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${config.PORT}`)
    });
```

but it not recognizes the variable PORT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly how you access environment variables in your local environment, You need to use **`process.env.ENV_VARIABLE`** to read environment variables in [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

```
var port = process.env.PORT;
```